# Having issues triggering Nessus Scan via API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am having issues triggering a Nessus Scan via the Softlayer API, I am using Java and making use of the library here: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java

This is the method I am using:

```
RestApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(xxxxxx, xxxxxxx);
Account.Service accountService = Account.service(client);
Account account = accountService.getObject();

Request.Service requestService = Request.service(client);

Request request = new Request();
request.setAccount(account);
request.setIpAddress(ipAddress);

Request scan = requestService.createObject(request);
```

I am getting knocked back with the issue:

> You are not allowed to start security scan requests on accounts other
>   than your own.

I am using the same credentials that I have used to provision multiple hosts via the API, so I am not sure why it's falling over here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is being thrown when the account is set instead of the account id.
You could try this Java example.

```
package SoftLayer_Java_Scripts.Examples;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.softlayer.api.*;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Account;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.security.scanner.Request;

public class CreateNetworkSecurityScannerRequest {

  private static String user = "set me";
  private static String apiKey = "set me";

  private static ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(user, apiKey);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Account.Service accountService = Account.service(client);
    Request.Service requestService = Request.service(client);
    String ipAddress = "168.1.11.156";
    Long virtualGuestId = 22358591L;

    Account account = null;
    try {
      account = accountService.getObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error retrieving account object.\nError message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setAccountId(account.getId());
    request.setGuestId(virtualGuestId);
    request.setIpAddress(ipAddress);
    Request scan = null;
    try {
      scan = requestService.createObject(request);
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      System.out.println(gson.toJson(scan));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error creating Network Security Scanner Request.\nError message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Change the example data with yours.